# Pynput trigger physical button press. Hotkey pressing not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, hotkeys, pynput, obs

The code is working fine the hotkey for the function is recognized and the buttons are being pressed.

An OBS function is triggered by the HotKey in hotkey_e().

When I press it physicaly it works. But when I run this script the obs function doesn't get triggered.

The only difference I've found through the print is that if you press the combination it prints <69> (for e) but if the script is pressing this combination it gives me a string "w"

[Print output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kDij.png)

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener, HotKey

kc = Controller()

def hotkey_e():
    kc.press(Key.alt_l)
    kc.press(Key.ctrl_l)
    kc.press(Key.shift)
    kc.press("w")
    kc.release(Key.alt_l)
    kc.release(Key.ctrl_l)
    kc.release(Key.shift)
    kc.release("w")

HOTKEYS = [HotKey(HotKey.parse("<shift>+<ctrl>+<alt>+" + "e"), hotkey_e)]

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        listener.stop()

    print(str(key))
    
    for hotkey in HOTKEYS:
        hotkey.press(listener.canonical(key))


def on_release(key):
    for hotkey in HOTKEYS:
        hotkey.release(listener.canonical(key))


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I also tried

```
with kc.pressed(Key.alt):
        with kc.pressed(Key.ctrl):
            with kc.pressed(Key.shift):
                kc.press("w")
                kc.release("w")
```

Edit:
I found out that if I the OBS windows is the active window the HotKey is working. But it should run in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to set some sleep between the key presses

```
def hotkey_e():
    kc.press(Key.alt_l)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.press(Key.ctrl_l)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.press(Key.shift)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.press("w")
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.release(Key.alt_l)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.release(Key.ctrl_l)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.release(Key.shift)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    kc.release("w")
```